# HttpClient in a .NET Library 1.6 gives error when used in .NET Framework or Unit Test

Tags: c#, .net-standard

I am currently developping an API Wrapper in **.NET Standard Library 1.6** and i came across a "problem" or a miss-understanding from my part.

I chose .Net Standard because it can be used in different platforms (.Net Core / .Net Framework etc) so I created a class that will handle the Http side of the API (makes  GET requests). Problem is the version of System.Net.Http in .Net Standard 1.6 is 4.3.0.0, but the version of System.Net.Http in .Net Framwork or Unit Test or even Nuget is 4.0.0.0.

This results into a fail in running an App that uses my library, saying that it didn't find the Assembly **System.Net.Http, Version=4.3.0.0**. Which brings me to my question(s):

- Why is the versions different?
- How can someone fix this? (right now i went to .Net Standard 1.1 to
  make it work)
- Is this a normal "behavior/system"?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `System.Net.Http`?

Comment: I think the question really is if you should use Net 4.0 (32 bits) or net 4.5 (64 bits).  You may have a mis-match between Net Versions.  If the API was built with 64 bit Net it will not run from an application built with 32 bit Net.

Comment: Which framework version you use? Because .NET Standard 1.6 cannot be referenced even by 4.6.2 as I remember.

Comment: Or which tooling version? (since the upcoming tooling will allow 4.6.1+ projects to reference .net standard up to 2.0, including 1.6)

Comment: - Sorry, it is indeed System.Net.Http
- I created the project in 1.6, used its version of HttpClient and wanted to test it in UnitTest / .Net Framework 4.6.x and it didn't work, saying it couldn't load the assembly, thus where i saw the version difference so I had to switch to .Net Standard 1.1; I just want to know why does standard 1.6 can't be used by other apps unless you downgrade to 1.1

Comment: Are you sure the error says `4.3.0.0`? it should be `4.1.1.0` (or `4.1.1.1`) using the latest released versions. Did you add the `NETStandard.Library` NuGet package to the test project?

Comment: I didn't know you should add the library to the test project, i'll test it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [@terrajobst on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/481#issue-254768258), you need to manually add the binding redirect properties to the .net framework project's csproj file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Binding redirects automatically get added to application project types, but not class libraries... which applies to unit test libraries, too.

The trick is that the HttpClient is signature-compliant with the full .Net Framework, and the minor releases appear to be internals changing that don't apply to the framework (possibly other platforms? I am unsure.) As a result, System.Net.Http 4.0.0.0 is the correct version for the .Net Framework, while 4.3.0 is the .Net Standard version number that applies. Binding redirects are the correct solution for this and several other cases.

I personally ran into the problem giving a `MissingMethodException`, and traced it down to an HttpClient version mismatch, exactly as you're describing. (I hope my including this comment helps save someone else the hour I spent trying to track it down!)

Comment: Many thanks for that, and for sufficient keywords to let Google lead me to your post...